# Show element during some time period, otherwise hide it

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, web, mobile-development

I'm using AngularJS, Ionic and Cordova to create a project and my question is pretty straight forward: How to show element, like div, during some time period(e.g. 8:00 15.2.2018. - 20:00 15.2.2018.), otherwise hide it?

EDIT:

This is what I got for now:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('module-name')
        .directive('timeRestricted', timeRestricted);

    timeRestricted.$inject = [ '$timeout' ]
    function timeRestricted($timeout) {
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A'
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var startTime = Date.parse(attrs.startTime);
            var endTime = Date.parse(attrs.endTime);
            var currentTime = new Date();

            var showTimeoutId = $timeout(
                function() {
                    console.log(`show: ${JSON.stringify(element)}`);
                    element.show();
                },
                currentTime - startTime
            )
            var hideTimeoutId = $timeout(
                function() {
                    console.log(`hide: ${JSON.stringify(element)}`);
                    element.hide();
                },
                endTime - startTime
            )

            element.on('$destroy', function() {
              $interval.cancel(showTimeoutId);
              $interval.cancel(hideTimeoutId);
              $interval.cancel(updateTimeoutId);
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Now I get `Error: element.hide is not a function` and same for `element.show`. I saw couple of examples showing similar usage of these functions and element in my example is a div tag which I use like this:

```
 <div time-restricted start-time={{vm.startTime}} end-time={{vm.endTime}>
 </div>
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate I added directive that I made but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Created a sample app to achieve the same. I tried for 5 seconds.

HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hi there!</p>
    <p ng-if="showPanel" style="padding: 10px; background-color: aquamarine;">I'll be visible sometime</p>
  </body>
```

Controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  var startTime = currentTime + 5000;
  //new Date(2018, 3, 15, 08, 00).getTime();
  var endTime = currentTime + 10000;
  //new Date(2018, 3, 15, 20, 00).getTime();

  $scope.showPanel = false;
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.showPanel = true;
  }, (currentTime - startTime ))  
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.showPanel = false;
  }, (endTime - startTime ))

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it as real-time then add the watcher on the time object based on it either add a class or ng-if in your HTML or simply put the date in your config and based on it hide or show the field